# Angular animation on a single item of an *ngFor list on swipe in ionic?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am trying to make an animation trigger when a swipe on an item in the list. Currently the animation triggers and works after a swipe, but it applies to the entire list. Is there any way for it to only trigger on the item that is swiped on?

In the HTML:

```
<ion-list *ngFor="let song of songList | async">
  <ion-item (swipeleft)="vote(song, true); toggleUpvoteAnim()" (swiperight)="vote(song, false)" class="bottom-border" [@myupvote]="upvoteState">
    {{song.title}}
    <div item-right>{{song.upVotes}}</div>
    <div item-right>UP</div>
    <div item-right>|</div>
    <div item-right>DOWN</div>
    <div item-right>{{song.downVotes}}</div>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

In the TS:

```
@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-guest-song-list',
  templateUrl: 'guest-song-list.html',
  animations: [
    trigger('myupvote', [
      state('noupvote', style({
        backgroundColor: '#191414'
      })),
      state('upvote', style({
        backgroundColor: '#191414'
      })),
      transition('* => *',
        animate('.25s', keyframes([
        style({backgroundColor: '#191414', offset: 0}),
        style({backgroundColor: '#1db954', offset: 0.25}),
        style({backgroundColor: '#191414', offset: 1})
        ]))
      )
    ])
  ]
})
export class GuestSongListPage {

  upvoteState = 'noupvote';
...
}
...
  toggleUpvoteAnim() {
    this.upvoteState = (this.upvoteState == 'upvote') ? 'noupvote ' : 'upvote';
  }
```

Comment: *ngFor is meant to be used on the ion-item element, not the ion-list element

Answer (score 0):

To fly the item from left to right, and on deletion, right to left with jurking

```
export const flyItems = [
  trigger('flyItems', [
    state('in', style({transform: 'translateX(0)'})),
    transition('void => *', [
      animate(700, keyframes([
        style({opacity: 0, transform: 'translateX(-100%)', offset: 0}),
        style({opacity: 1, transform: 'translateX(0)',     offset: 1.0})
      ]))
    ]),
    transition('* => void', [
      animate(500, keyframes([
        style({opacity: 1, transform: 'translateX(0)',     offset: 0}),
        style({opacity: 0, transform: 'translateX(100%)',  offset: 1.0})
      ]))
    ])
  ])
];
```

[See this page, try to add and remove items, might be you need the same thing](http://www.advancesharp.com/blog/1228/angular-5-reusable-animation-with-a-single-file)

Comment: I tried to do it as in the example but it didn't work, in fact it broke the list instead?